# How to automate connect to a ssh server with keyboard-interactive authentication using jsch lib in java

Tags: java, ssh, jsch

I want to automate connect to a ssh server with keyboard-interactive authentication(or challenge-response authentication) using jsch.
I'd already set userinfo and config like this.

```
session.setUserInfo(myUserInfo);
session.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
session.setConfig("PreferredAuthentications",
                    "publickey,keyboard-interactive,password");
```

myUserInfo object implement the [UserInfo interface](https://epaul.github.io/jsch-documentation/javadoc/com/jcraft/jsch/UserInfo.html)
When I debug the source, I'm always getting a com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: Auth fail exception.
Somebody said myUserInfo should implement [UIKeyboardInteractive](https://epaul.github.io/jsch-documentation/javadoc/com/jcraft/jsch/UIKeyboardInteractive.html).
But I can't understand the official JSch UserAuthKI example. It's too complicated to understand.
I just want get a connection automate.
Who can give me a simple example, please.
Thanks.

Comment: It's not answering your question, but when automating ssh connections it's best practice to use public key authentication.

Answer (score 0):

I found solution.
Let's myUserInfo class implements UIKeyboardInteractive interface.
And rewrited promptKeyboardInteractive method like this.

```
@Override
public String[] promptKeyboardInteractive(String destination, String name,
                                              String instruction, String[] prompt,
                                              boolean[] echo)
{
       System.out.println("#####promptKeyboardInteractive#####");
       System.out.println("destination: " + destination);
       System.out.println("name: " + name);
       System.out.println("instruction: " + instruction);
       System.out.println("prompt.length: " + prompt.length);
       System.out.println("prompt[0]: " + prompt[0]);
       System.out.println("echo[0]: " + echo[0]);
       String[] response=new String[prompt.length];
       response[0] = passwd;
       return response;
}
```

It's works. I can get a connection from the ssh server.